# Minimize/ Maximize Code Visual Studios (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Hey is there anyway that in your program you can add a minimize/ maximize icon on the side anywhere. (like Below). I want to be able to minimize and maximize certain sections if it is at all possible. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: you mean : `CTRL M + M` ??????.........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you can already (asin, by default) collapse any code with braces, but don't have VS on hand to confirm this.

For collapsing absolutely anything, you could use `#region [name]` and `#endregion`.

Actually, looking straight at the [documentation for hiding code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td6a5x4s.aspx) you can select code, right click it, go to 'Outlining' and choose 'Hide Selection'. This would have the same effect as creating and collapsing a region, apart from regions are named (thus explaining what is contained within, which is probably easier for you to keep track of if it's for large groups of code).

Comment: Yeah you can as long as it has brackets, but I was just seeing if you could highlight or something and then just add the collapsible sign to it, but I am going to go that route Thank you

Comment: @RussellSaari You can just highlight something and add the collapsible sign, see my updated answer.

Comment: @RussellSaari No problem, this will always be a better solution than regions if you're using them often. Regions are generally used to separate large chunks of code (not so large as to be split into classes).

Answer (score 5):

Use [regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx).

```
private void SomeCallback()
{
    #region This chunk of code does something.
    DoSomething();
    #endregion

    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

The region on its own will be collapsible (and, as usual, so will the `SomeCallback()` method body).

You can specify the `#region` and `#endregion` directives anywhere in your source file, but make sure to place them where it makes sense, and don't overuse them.

Comment: That is what I was thinking of doing something along those lines thanks.

Comment: Please _only_ use them at root level, though, not in methods as illustrated here, or in the body of properties, et cetera, (doing so is nothing more than avoidance of appropriate refactoring.)